# How to query 3 tables in db for minimum time

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-alarms

If I have a db with 3 tables A, B, and C. These tables each have a timestamp column.

How can I query the 3 tables to get the row with the least timestamp (closest to now).

I can query each separately and get the minimum timstamp of each table and then do a compare in code but I think there must be a more efficient way.

I want to do it because, I want to schedule an alarm for the NEXT expire date instead of scheduling alarms for all timestamps. I am using SQLITE.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to form a unified select query from 3 of them, for example if table A has 3 column and table B has two column , write a three column selection for both of them and use for example '' as 3rd column . then you can use `Union` and `Order` by to achieve you final query.(because I didn't know your tables structures I just used A.*,b.*,C.*)

```
with temp as (
    SELECT A.* Table_Name FROM A
UNION SELECT B.* as Table_Name FROM B
UNION SELECT C.* as Table_Name FROM C
)
select top(1) temp.* from temp Order By temp.TS where temp.TS<TimeNow
```

Comment: accepted this answer for the elaboration and for the ability to select full row

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(TS), Table_Name FROM (
SELECT MIN(TS) AS TS, 'A' as Table_Name FROM A
UNION SELECT MIN(TS) AS TS, 'B' as Table_Name FROM B
UNION SELECT MIN(TS) AS TS, 'C' as Table_Name FROM C);
```

Comment: Hmmm I see.Thats great, however does that return me the row containing the minimum TS. I need the full row that has the min TS

Comment: No That won't return row with Minimum TS as only TS column is using Aggregate function so if you want to access other information as well then you have Table Name and MIN TS now, you can fire query like SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TimeST= TS; OR you can also look for Inner query

Comment: SQLite actually allows using non-aggregate columns together with aggregate functions.